# Boost Libraries on Monodevelop

Tags: c++, boost, monodevelop

I am trying to link some Boost `.hpp` files with Monodevelop, but I don't know how to tell the IDE where Libraries are.

If I want to include the `array.hpp` file, I write `#include<directories/array.hpp>`, but because this file makes calls to other files, and the directories to those files in the `array.hp`p file are only `/boost/somefile`, there are several path errors. What can I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For libraries like Boost you'll need to add the path to the includes/libraries in your project configuration.

In MonoDevelop this can be done by choosing *Project->Options->Configurations*, then choose the appropriate build type (you'll probably want to edit both Debug and Release eventually), and then *Code Generation->Paths*.

The *Library* section is for your built libraries, if any, and the *Include* section is for stuff like headers and includes.

In this particular case you'll want to add `/usr/local/boost` to the *Include* section (change the path as necessary).

Once you've done that, you should be able to use Boost like so:

```
 #include <boost/array.hpp> // make sure you use angle brackets
```